# CPAN install into temp directory?

Tags: perl, rpm, cpan, rpmbuild, cpanm

I'm trying to install quite a few modules from CPAN into a temporary directory.

This is purely to place quite a few of them into a directory that I can then create a custom RPM out of. The rpm will then later be used on new installs as a bootstrap type thing on top of a custom perl install. They won't be run from this temporary location.

In CPAN I have tried

```
o conf mbuildpl_arg "--install_base /tmp/perl"
o conf makepl_arg "PREFIX=/tmp/perl"
```

But this seems to install them into /root/.cpan/build/somename/tmp/perl (where 'somename' varies each time), or the usual location. I was hoping to capture them all into a temporary buildroot type folder, that I can rpm them into the correct folder later.

Is there any way to do this, or am I doing something that isn't a good idea ?

I've looked into fpm and cpan2rpm but couldn't see a way to do lots of Perl modules into one RPM, so happy for any better thoughts on how to go from lots of modules to one custom RPM.

Comment: I use `perlbrew` to get my own copy of Perl. When I switch to its Perl, the `cpan` automatically switches so anything I load will only be local. See http://perlbrew.pl/

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to avoid cpan entirely though (other than for first time around, every time after that would be via rpm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that will install them in `/tmp/perl` (unless you override the arguments from `cpan` with an environment variables). They're not installed in `~/.cpan/build`. That is where the modules are built (by `make` or `Build`) before they are installed (by `make install` or `Build install`). You can wipe that directory whenever you want.

---

By the way, you're telling ExtUtils::MakeMaker and Module::Build to use two different conventions. That's bad.

```
o conf mbuildpl_arg "--install_base /tmp/perl"
o conf makepl_arg "PREFIX=/tmp/perl"
```

should be

```
o conf mbuildpl_arg "--install_base /tmp/perl"
o conf makepl_arg "INSTALL_BASE=/tmp/perl"
```

or

```
o conf mbuildpl_arg "--prefix /tmp/perl"
o conf makepl_arg "PREFIX=/tmp/perl"
```

Personally, when I used local modules before I used local builds of Perl, I used

```
o conf mbuildpl_arg "--prefix /tmp/perl --lib /tmp/perl/lib/perl5"
o conf makepl_arg "PREFIX=/tmp/perl LIB=/tmp/perl/lib/perl5"
```

I dislike `INSTALL_BASE` as it makes it hard to upgrade your `perl` smoothly.

Comment: Yes, I want them installed into /tmp/perl, this is what I want, but its not doing that currently. I just want a directory for with the newly installed modules and any depencies. I will try your suggestion thanks.

Comment: Either you didn't ask to install anything, the installation is failing, or you are overriding the parameters passed by `cpan` using env vars `PERL_MM_OPT` and/or `PERL_MB_OPT`

Comment: Thanks, I think maybe some installs are failing. Eg install ExtUtils::XSBuilder::ParseSource says GRICHTER/ExtUtils-XSBuilder-0.28.tar.gz      : make_test NO 2 dependencies missing (Tie::IxHash,Parse::RecDescent). But install Tie::IxHash says already installed. Do these methods conflict somehow with how they look for existing dependencies ?

Comment: Did you tell Perl where to look for the modules by setting env var `PERL5LIB`?

Comment: Thanks for persisting, I was trying export PERL5LIB=/tmp/perl/lib/5.14.2/:/tmp/perl/lib/site_perl/:/opt/perl/lib/5.14.2/:/opt/perl/lib/site_perl/ but I get that dependency error or 'already built but the result looks suspicious. Skipping another build attempt' (not on all modules, some do install ok, but a fair portion of them)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, as I still have some problems, but I think probably unrelated to the original question. Thanks ikegami

Comment: (Probably should be `export PERL5LIB=/tmp/perl/lib`) I've never seen that message. Make sure `build_dir_reuse` is still false (`0`)?